# ServerVariables["UNENCODED_URL"] is empty when I try to access it in my MVC Action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, request.servervariables

I'm writing a catch-all action method for a 404 page that takes the requested URL, extracts the wordy bits with a regex `(\w+)*` and sends those bits, space-separated, to the search engine to generate a list of suggested pages.

The problem is, `ServerVariables["UNENCODED_URL"]` appears to be unavailable here in the Action method. Other server variables *are* available, however.

I could use `ServerVariables["URL"]` in conjunction with `ServerVariables["QUERY_STRING"]`, both of which are available. But in some situations this leaves out parts of the URL that might contain valid info regarding the user's intention.

For example, if the mal-formed URL is

```
/test/007/words/something-with-a-dot.xyz/these-words-are-neglected/?stuff-in-querystring
```

Then the "URL" and "QUERY_STRING" are found as `"/test/007/words/something-with-a-dot.xyz"` and `"stuff-in-querystring"`

"URL" ignores rather bluntly everything after what looks like a file extension. So it doesn't suffice.

**So what's up with UNENCODED_URL?**
And how can I get its equivalent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the HTTP_URL variable?  Looks like it returns the raw, encoded URL, for example, "/vdir/default.asp?querystring" - from MSDN.

[Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524602%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Also - if you are in a controller's action method, you could(should?) use the HttpContext in place of the SERVER[someProperty].  Something like:

```
var Url = HttpContext.Request.RawUrl;
```

which returns the full URL of the current request.

Comment: That's it! -- HttpContext.Request.RawUrl. BTW, I was trying HttpContext.Request.ServerVariables["UNENCODED_URL"], but kept it short in the post.